# How to use media query to block parallax at certain width in bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I would like to block the parallax effect when screen width reaches less than 800px, however, it doesn't seem like my css is working:

```
.parallax{
background-image:url(resources/newbg.png);
height:100vh;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
```

and the css for the screen size:

```
    @media (min-width: 800x) {
.parallax{
background-image:url(resources/newbg.png) !important;
height:100vh !important;
background-attachment:scroll !important;
background-position:center !important;
background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
background-size:cover !important;
}}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome qpeo to SO, could you explain more using `html` source and image also.

Comment: Hi ArifMustafa, for the background-image:url (i use a background image) and i use <div class="parallax"></div> to display the image, but i want to disable it when screen width is smaller than 800px;

Comment: Try using `@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {  ....  }` also you have missed `p` in 800x.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, i try to resize my browser and it still does the parallax. could it be because of the browser? or is the code not working?

Comment: Then you have to share your full source code, otherwise we are unable to help you.

Comment: It works, actually all i did was change the @media screen and (min-width: 800px) to max-width: 800px and it worked. Thank you for your help.